# Could Not Find Inverse Association for has_many in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have the following models:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers, :inverse_of => :business
  has_many :payments, :inverse_of => :business
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business, :inverse_of => :customer
  has_many :payments, :inverse_of => :customer 
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :payment 
  belongs_to :business, :inverse_of => :payment
end
```

Doing `business.customers` works fine. However, when I do `business.payments` I get an error: `Could not find the inverse association for business (:payment in Business)`.

I'm not sure why though. I have the same exact associations both ways. My schema.db also looks fine. What could be the issue here?

**EDIT**
When I remove the `inverse_of => :business` for `has_many :payments`, it works. Why does this happen? Is it related to that Payment belongs to customer and business (it shouldn't really matter, right?)?

Comment: did you apply the proper rake commands for update the associations in the DB?

Comment: @wandarkaf yes, db:migrate. The associations were there from when I did my first migration. Please see above edit.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Update Payment model with this:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :payments 
  belongs_to :business, :inverse_of => :payments
end
```

you declared

`has_many :payments, :inverse_of => :business` in Business model

but  in Payment you used `belongs_to :business, :inverse_of => :payment`

it should be `belongs_to :business, :inverse_of => :payments`

Comment: The main point is that you must use proper pluralization for inverse_of: arguments. If it is inverse of many payments, use :payments, not :payment. Similar for business

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at:

```
belongs_to :business, :inverse_of => :customer
```

and at:

```
belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :payment 
belongs_to :business, :inverse_of => :payment
```

The other side of `belongs_to` is `has_many`, which defines a plural relation. That means the `inverse_of` should be `customers` instead of `customer` and `payments` instead of `payment`.